# == and is not returning the same even though comparing an int

Tags: python

I'm using the `pow` function and found out I had a bug in my code because `==` and `is` were not having the same behavior.

Here goes an example: `pow(3, 47159012670, 47159012671) == 1` returns `True` but `pow(3, 47159012670, 47159012671) is 1` returns `False`.

I'd like to know what is it that I'm not getting.

Comment: `1` uses the cached `1` object; `pow(...)` creates a new `1`.

Comment: People too commonly treat CPython's small integer caching as if it's an actual guarantee. As demonstrated here, it's not a guarantee, even in CPython.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `is` and `==` is:

```
a1 is a2 # return True
```

only when they share the same location or id in memory, that means when `id(a1)` and `id(a2)` are the same. I hope [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ8bZPqtwU0&t=1s) will help more.

Comment: At least explain when somebody down votes, may be there is something for me to learn from my mistakes))

Comment: Thinking about this in terms of memory locations is like trying to distinguish whether two humans are the same human by seeing whether they're sitting in the same chair. Also, the Python language is not defined in terms of memory locations, and some Python implementations (e.g. PyPy) will return `True` for `is` even if two (or more!) memory locations happen to be used for the arguments.

Comment: I understand more now. Thanks